# Wordpress Multisite first/main site $post variable is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to set up a multisite and everything works perfect on the subdomains but on the main site I cannot reach any content. Especially the `$post` is empty and `WP_Query` and `get_posts` functions returns an empty array.
the `$wp_query` object is exists but returns nothing.

The multisite network structure (using folder routing):

- mySite -> this is the main site, this should show something global (no results for query)
- mySite/en -> content for England specific content (everything works)
- mySite/de -> content for Germany specific content (everything works)

All using the same theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just realised that I have a polylang plugin. 
It should be fine, but the content was published before the plugin activation. After I republished the pages and posts everything were going to fine.